# Getting ORA-00947: not enough values error while inserting date into table

Tags: oracle, insert, date

I have created a table

```
    create table Times ( 
departure date not null, 
arrival date not null, 

)
```

and I need to insert date and time in both columns

```
    insert into Times(departure, arrival) 
values (to_date ('2018-05-02 12:40', '2018-05-02 15:08'))
```

I get the following error

```
ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only inserting one column value, not both. The second parameter in to_date should be the format used by the first parameter, not another date. Your insert should look like this:

```
insert into times (departure, arrival) values 
  (to_date('2018-05-02 12:40','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'),
   to_date('2018-05-02 15:08','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
```